# Isn't this patent basically talking about picture phone and a server capable of storing photos combined?

Tags: us6038295

Isn't this patent basically talking about picture phone and a server capable of storing photos combined? i mean both of these technologies are already known before this patent, then how were they able to get this patent??

Answer (score 1):

It talks about taking pictures with your phone and uploading those to a server. It has been filed in 1997 and considering that the first camera phone was sold in 2000 in Japan, 3 years after the patent was filed and the same year it was published, I don't see where the issue lies in awarding this patent to Siemens.

Comment: At&T took out the first videophone in 1969 and Video conferencing has existed since the 70's and 80's. Due to high costs and insufficient bandwidth infrastructure, it never achieved public acceptance. In 2000, this technology became viable enough to be sold commercially and hence the first camera phone in Japan in 2000. The point being, the technology already existed!

Comment: If you read through the patent, you will see that it is about a mobile phone with digital camera. I would hardly call AT&T's videophone as mobile, and certainly it wasn't digital. It also lacked the other capabilities described in the patent, like adding tags and annotations using speech-to-text technology.